# Some HTML tags in page don't work on adding div

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, hyperlink

The problem that I am currently facing is that I the links that are attached to the HOME and ABOUT ME options (see in header) are not available on adding the 'data' div. However, the links for DOWNLOAD and CONTACT ME are still available. This issue occurs on Chrome and Firefox. It works fine on IE.

On removing the 'data' div all links work as per expectation.

Please help me understand where I am going wrong and how I can correct it.

HTML:

```
    <body>
         <h1 align="center">Hello</h1>
         <div id="main_body">
            <div id="leftPanel">
                <div id="header">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a>|</li>
                        <li><a href="AboutMe.html">ABOUT ME</a>|</li>
                        <li><a href="Download.html">DOWNLOAD</a>|</li>
                        <li><a href="ContactMe.html">CONTACT ME</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="data">
                    <p>hi</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 0 0px 0; 
    background-color:#000000;
    color:white;
}

div, p, ul, li, form, h2, img, textarea, h3, li {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}

#main_body {
    width:760px; 
    margin:20px auto; 
    font-size:0; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#leftPanel {
    width:760px; 
    height:677px; 
    background:url(/img/resume_background.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 #000000;
}

#header {
    position:absolute; 
    width:450px; 
    margin:40px 0px 0px 315px;  
    color:#FAF8F2; 
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:0; 
    height:35px; 
    padding:24px 0 0 0; 
    display:block;
}
#header ul {
    margin-top:-20px; 
    margin-left:20px;
}
#header ul li {
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
    font:9pt Arial; 
    color:#F1E9D6;
}

#header ul li a {
    font:normal 9pt Arial; 
    color:#F1E9D6;  
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    text-decoration:none; 
}

#header ul li a:hover {
    color:#2b8cf3;
}

#header p {
    text-align:center; 
    font:normal 9pt Arial; 
    color:#F1E9D6;  
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    text-decoration:none; 
}

#header p.text {
    width:200px; 
    display:block;  
    margin:8px 0 0 110px; 
    color:#E9DFC6; 
    background-color:#707070; 
    font:bold 8pt Arial;  
    float:left; 
    padding:0 0 0 12px; 
    text-align:center;
}

#header p.text a {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    padding:0 0 0 5px;
}

#header p.text a:hover {
    background-color:#403722; 
    color:#F1E9D6;
}

#data {
    position:relative; 
    width:450px;   
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:0; 
    height:35px; 
    padding:100px 0 0 0; 
    display:block;
}
#data p {
    text-align:center; 
    font:bold 12pt Georgia; 
    color:#F1E9D6;  
    padding:20px 10px 10px 10px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
}
#data p.text {
    width:200px; 
    display:block;  
    margin:8px 0 0 110px; 
    color:#E9DFC6; 
    background-color:#707070; 
    font:bold 8pt Arial;   
    padding:0 0 0 12px; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!
:)

Comment: The problem is that #data covers it. You cannot click through layers in a common case. You can add to your css rules `div#data { pointer-events: none }` or you may add a z-index to your menu like this: `#header { z-index: 1000; }` and there are lots of other choices depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your data div is overlaying those links. Aside from changing its position, you add the CSS rule [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the data div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kP4CL/)**

```
#data {
    position:relative;
    width:450px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:0;
    height:35px;
    padding:100px 0 0 0;
    display:block;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your #data div is overlapping the other content on the page, in this case your home and about me links. I am not sure where you want the #data div to display, but try adding a background-color or border to the #data div (so you can see its content area) and adjust its position using margins or positions. Alternatively you could use z-index to place the #data div 'behind' your links.